# Regex to match values in multiple files

Tags: regex, redhat

I have a bunch of php files on a linux (redhat) filesystem, the majority of the files seem to be OK as they are using functions which abstract database interactions, however I have found some places where inline queries are used instead of the abstraction layer functions

These queries seem to be designed to run with mysql but we are running Oracle so they create failures when checking for empty values for example:

```
select name from user where name !=''
```

In Oracle this query will never return any rows and I need to change it like so:

```
select name from user where name !=' '
```

I have been able to fix this in the file I went through now I would like to proactively find any places where this occurs in other files; however there are lots of .php files across many directories to be checked

Is it possible to run a search in all .php files below a certain directory for occurrences of text such as ='' or != ''

Here is a real example from one of the files in /lib/ where an embedded query is used

```
$rs = $DB->get_recordset_sql (
"SELECT *
    FROM {user}
        WHERE confirmed = 1 AND lastaccess > 0
        AND lastaccess < ? AND deleted = 0
        AND (lastname = '' OR firstname = '' OR email = '')"
```

I was thinking something along the lines of looking for a double apostrophe nested within double quotes along these lines \".*\''.*\"
but am not that confident with linux to make the search work and be able to iterate over multiple files!

```
\$DB->.*".*''.*"
```

works if it were on a single line but obviously not in the example I've given : looking at using SED to do this match over multiple (n) lines now

Answer (score 1):

```
find topdir -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep -l "= *''" {} +
```

`grep` operates a line at a time, so it can't match your example by looking for apostrophes within double quotes, because they're on different lines. So I'm just checking for `= ''`.

The `-l` option prints the names of the matching files, rather than printing the matching lines.